# SET/RESET command in ALTER DATABASE is not supported

Tags: amazon-redshift

Encountered this issue when trying to modify the search_path to my new Redshift db.

Presently, I've migrated the contents of my MySQL db into a redshift cluster via AWS' Data Migration Service. The data was imported into a schema lets call my_schema. When I try to execute queries against the cluster it requires me to prefix table names with the schema name

i.e.

`select * from my_schema.my_table`

I wanted to change the setup so that I can reference the table directly without needing the prefix. After a bit of looking around I found out that this was possible by modifying the `search_path` attribute.

First I tried doing this by running

`set search_path = "$user", my_schema;`

This appeared to work but then I realized that this was simply setting my_schema as the default schema in the context of the current session, I wanted it set on a database level. I found several sources saying that the way to do this was to use the alter command like so...

`alter database my_db set search_path = "$user", public, my_schema`

However, running this command results in the following error which somehow shows up in 0 google results:

`SET/RESET commmand in ALTER DATABASE is not supported`

I'm pretty baffled by how the above error hasn't ever had a post made about it but I'm also pretty interested in figuring out how to resolve my initial issue of setting a global default schema for my redshift cluster.

Comment: [Postgres and Amazon Redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html) are two different systems. [ALTER DATABASE in the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_DATABASE.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ALTER DATABASE SET`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_DATABASE.html) is not supported in Redshift. However you can SET/RESET configuration parameters at USER level using the `ALTER USER SET SEARCH_PATH TO <SCHEMA1>,<SCHMEA2>;`

Please check: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_USER.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_search_path.html

When you set the `search_path` to `<SCHEMA1>,<SCHMEA2>` in `db1` for a user it is not for just current session, it will be set for all future sessions.